# Error: Cannot find module 'p-map' when running npm start on create-react-app project

Tags: create-react-app

Encounters this error when running npm start on newly created create-react-app project:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'p-map'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jeff ramos\Documents\web-dev\react-framework-intro-2\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\del\index.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-framework-intro-2@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-framework-intro-2@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Try running `yarn` or `npm i` again. It'll install dependencies that might have been missed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

`npm install p-map`